# How is this valid javascript, and what purpose does it serve?

Tags: javascript

I was answering a question on quora and encountered something like following:

```
// if(true)
{
   var qq = 1;
}
```

Immediately I fired up chrome and tried the following

```
{
   var qq = 1;
}
```

To my surprise no syntax errors. I thought this might be a way to set up a closure without a function, but alas nothing like that is true.

Why is this valid JavaScript? Does this serve some purpose? Are there any issues due to this?

Comment: i can say it just a mistake ! which can't break your program execution but in ES6 it will play major role as it introduced curly bracket scopes just like java and c#. So a memeber defined inside these curly bracket will not be accessible outside

Comment: @MohammadFaizankhan you'll only get block scoping if you use `let` or `const`. `var` will act the same as it always has

Comment: @Cory  ES6 also require it??

Comment: You only get block scoping if you define a variable with let or const. `var x = 0; { let x = 11; var y = 12; } // x+y = 12;`

Comment: "Questioning everything about JavaScript" seems a bit extreme.

Comment: @torazaburo fineee corrected.

Comment: I have seen this used as a way to delineate blocks of code for readability, which I don't think is a totally horrible idea.

Comment: @torazaburo ya, I guess I was also trying to see if anyone found that annoying or positive in their code bases.

Answer (score 2):

It is a [block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block).

[Syntactically](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-block), a block is just a bunch of statements that are grouped together.

```
Block : { StatementList }
StatementList
    : StatementListItem
    | StatementList StatementListItem
StatementListItem
    : Statement
    | Declaration
```

But here's the tricky part: blocks are statements, too.

```
Statement : BlockStatement
BlockStatement : Block
```

And there you have it, now you can define compound statements such as `if` or `while` in terms of an abstract `Statement`, without having to worry about whether it is a single statement or a block.

```
IfStatement
    : if ( Expression ) Statement else Statement
    | if ( Expression ) Statement
IterationStatement
    : while ( Expression ) Statement
    | for ( LeftHandSideExpression in Expression ) Statement
    | for ( LeftHandSideExpression of AssignmentExpression ) Statement
```

Isn't it beautiful?

As a side effect of this language design, blocks can contain other blocks inside — it isn't worth prohibiting this quirk explicitly in the language specification, although semantically in EcmaScript 5.1 inner blocks were indeed superfluous and very rarely used.

```
{
    var x = 1;
    {
        var x = 2; // The same variable as in the outer block.
        console.log(x); //=> 2
    }
    console.log(x); //=> 2
}
```

In the latest EcmaScript 6 (2015) standard, however, such blocks do have semantic value, as shown in the next example:

```
{
    let x = 1;
    {
        let x = 2; // New variable, visible in this block only.
        console.log(x); //=> 2
    }
    console.log(x); //=> 1
}
```

[`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) are block-scoped variable declarations introduced by ES6.

Comment: Ohhh crazy, I thought one of the main properties of a block was having block scoping. I guess you can have blocks without that, that makes sense. This makes more sense in terms of es6 though.

Comment: Conceptually yes, but terminologically no. A block not a "statement", it's a, well, block. The two are different. `if` is not an "operator", it's a keyword.

Comment: @torazaburo It is unfortunate I didn't separate the concepts initially. I hope now my answer makes it clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The blocks are used just for statements like `if(){}, function(){}, switch(){}, for(..){}, etc`.

**In this example:**

```
var number = 0;
if(true)
    number = 1
else
    number = 2
    number = 3 //This line is evaluated because no longer is in the `else` condition

console.log(number); //3
```

Using blocks this will not happen:

```
var number = 0;
if(true)
{
    number = 1
}
else
{
    number = 2
    number = 3
}

console.log(number); //1
```

> Using blocks without using any statement **are unnecessary**, eg:

```
var foo = 2;
foo = 3;
console.log(foo) //3
```

**It is the same as doing:**

```
var foo = 2;
{
    foo = 3;
}
console.log(foo) //3
```

**Except** if you are developing in an environment of ES6. Using [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) declarations in blocks are very important. And these will be evaluated only within the block.

```
let foo = 2;
{
    let foo = 3;
}

console.log(foo) //2
```